# What does the tag <<= mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know what the tag `<<=` means in JavaScript?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var temp = 14;
            var y = 2;
            temp <<= y;
            document.write(temp);
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't know what an operator in a language means, read the documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators

Comment: It's not a tag, it is an operator.

Answer (score 1):

[Left shift assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Left_shift_assignment).

Straight from docs:

```
var bar = 5; //    (00000000000000000000000000000101)
bar <<= 2;   // 20 (00000000000000000000000000010100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shift left in place.
Divides the value in the variable on the left by two to the power of the value on the right.

Answer (score 0):

This line `temp <<= y` equals to `temp = temp << y`. And this expression can be interpreted as `temp = parseInt(temp.toString(2) + '0'.repeat(y),2)`.